# Sometimes need to refresh multiple time to load website build on Angular 14

Tags: angular14

I am facing intermittent issues with my website built on Angular 14. Sometimes it loads perfectly but sometimes it shows a blank page and Just after refresh it loads again.

I am loading multiple external Javascript libraries like Google Maps, Razorpay,daterangepicker, and others on the index.html file.

So I am concerned about

Does it happen due to me because I am loading it on index.html? If yes then where we should load this library and how.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: please share your code on stakbiz, we cant help you with limited description

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your calls in onInit() function, perhaps you are using constructor for that.